# VBA function to multiply odd numbers in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel VBA and trying to write a VBA function to multiply odd numbers in a range.  I am using the SumEvenNumbers(rng) function as a starting point but I can't figure out how to turn it into what I want.
This is what I have so far:

```
Function SumEvenNumbers(rng)
    SumEvenNumbers = 0
    Counter = 0
    Numeven = 0
    For Each Cel In rng
        Counter = Counter + 1
            If Cel.Value Mod 2 = 0 Then
                Numeven = Numeven + 1
                SumEvenNumbers = SumEvenNumbers + Cel.Value
            End If
        Debug.Print Counter, Numeven, SumEvenNumbers
    Next Cel
End Function

'multiply odd numbers
Function MultiplyOddNumbers(rng)
    MultiplyOddNumbers = 0
    Counter = 0
    MultOdd = 0
    For Each Cel In rng
        Counter = Counter + 1
            If Cel.Value Mod 2 = 1 Then
                MultiplyOddNumbers = MultiplyOddNumbers * Cel.Value
            End If
        Debug.Print Counter, MultOdd, MultiplyOddNumbers
    Next Cel
End Function
```

Comment: Your initial value of `MultiplyOddNumbers` is zero, causing the product of each multiplication to be zero as well. Change the initial value to 1 and count the odd numbers, if there are no odd numbers in the range, you can then reset the value to zero at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultiplyOddNumbers is always going to be 0 because you never assigned a different value to it. You’re just multiplying the cell value by 0 every time.

Change

```
MultiplyOddNumbers = 0
```

to

```
MultiplyOddNumbers = 1
```

and your code will work as desired